# Issue On Inlining Drop Down Menu on XS Displays

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Sxy93VwOgt) and let me know how I can change the Drop Down List style to `list-inline` only on `Xs`displays:

right now what Standard Bootstrap is providing  is like this:
[image]

But I need to displat them in one line like

[image]

can you please let me know how to do this only on Phone size displays (xs)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the list items a class like `.social-icon`

```
<li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
<li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
```

Then make them and the anchors inside `inline-block`

```
.navbar-nav .social-icon,
.navbar-nav .social-icon > a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/P40xyp4f28)